# Google Maps Radius

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'd like to know if it's possible to put a **radius delimiter in Google maps**!?
For example: I select a region or a city and I had a 5 mile radius and the delimiter increases, drawing it!

Please consider this example: I choose "Amsterdam" as the place, and then I add 5km to it and it will return the results from "Amsterdam" plus the 5km radius

http://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/+5km/

My problem is I dont understand how to add 5km to "Amsterdam" since it cant be the center point - I think I need the delimiter for the region "Amsterdam". Does this exist on Google maps API or any other API?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear to me. Are you trying to limit the search radius?

Comment: no! i'm trying to draw a line automatically around a place(coordinates) in a map!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

[Map Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts?hl=nl)

as per your requirement, i think the above link will help you.

Try this,

```
// Create marker 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.7433,-104.9872),
  title: 'Some location'
});

// Add circle overlay and bind to marker
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 8047,    // 5 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000'
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Reference:
http://seriouscodage.blogspot.in/2010/11/visualizing-data-as-circles-in-google.html

Comment: This is not the way i want! sorry i explained badly! i want to delimit around a place not a circle but more like a border of a district!

Comment: So you would like to keep the shape of a city for example, and apply a padding around it?

Comment: like this! 
http://mt0.google.com/vt/data=ezluM6774wDRXK37maJy9uz2xGnSEL1VrAK11-ALVYR1tCj-Cdr6k40HvTs-0QJwcDJcukllhxAAcfND_x_ECVqHREaDbSM1D8MRCAq8AA6pJdREJcCPcVTuBbi96r2FtaYOuDCbIBSQOc9PqcewJJWjyrQXTcvLm2CD_IfPmWAvt_U4TT8YsHMJ4FWxcxuMCNnWemKh4oZp3gKkgl4Hy16MRuaxkg